# Bash: Search for consecutive repetitions of a pattern and replace it with a string containing the number of repetitions

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I used pandoc to convert a .docx file to .tex. The original file was a fill in the blank where the blanks were created using the `_` character repeatedly.

In .tex this has been literally converted to `\_` by pandoc. However, there are little spaces between the underscores and overall the blanks are too long.

I'd like to find strings like `\_\_\_` (three repetitions of `\_`) and substitute them by a tex command like `\rule[-0.1ex]{3em}{0.5pt}`. In general, if N is the number of repetitions, then it would be `\rule[-0.1ex]{N em}{0.5pt}`.

Since all the blanks have various sizes, I need to match for all possible lengths. I read about groups in sed, but couldn't figure out how to use them here. I'm not proficient at regex at all and am somewhat overwhelmed with the cryptic regex patterns I could find so far...

Adding requested information:

Here is a possible input:

```
this is some text
\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_

there is some more text

even more text here
\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_.

\hfill\par

text text text
\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_.

\hfill\par

\textbf{Teilmenge}

Some text here: \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_, and more text as well    \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_.
```

Here is the expected output:

```
this is some text
\rule[-0.1ex]{42em}{0.5pt}

there is some more text

even more text here
\rule[-0.1ex]{24em}{0.5pt}.

\hfill\par

text text text
\rule[-0.1ex]{37em}{0.5pt}.

\hfill\par

\textbf{Teilmenge}

Some text here: \rule[-0.1ex]{10em}{0.5pt}, and more text as well \rule[-0.1ex]{31em}{0.5pt}.
```

I don't have anything working as command, but something along the lines of

```
echo "$TEST" | sed 's/([\\\_]+)/\rule[-0.1ex]{length(\1) em}{0.5pt}/'
```

Comment: Please add a sample input, expected output and your attempted command

Comment: You could find-replace `N` repetitions of `\_` with `...N em...` for all `N` using `N` manual find-replace operations. You have to start with the max of `N` of course. If `N` is not too big this might be the fastest solution.

Comment: It's not clear if the block of text in your question is the sample input or expected output. Whichever it is - add the other one that's currently missing to complete the example as we can't test a potential solution with just input or just output, we need both.

Comment: The question is already solved, but I added the requested information for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is not the right tool for this. I suggest using an `awk` solution like this:

```bash
awk '{
for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
   if ($i ~ /\\_/)
      $i = "\\rule[-0.1ex]{" gsub(/\\_/, "", $i) "em}{0.5pt}" $i
} 1' file

this is some text
\rule[-0.1ex]{42em}{0.5pt}

there is some more text

even more text here
\rule[-0.1ex]{24em}{0.5pt}.

\hfill\par

text text text
\rule[-0.1ex]{37em}{0.5pt}.

\hfill\par

\textbf{Teilmenge}

Some text here: \rule[-0.1ex]{10em}{0.5pt}, and more text as well \rule[-0.1ex]{31em}{0.5pt}.
```

Note that `gsub` function returns number of replacements in the output and we use that number to construct the output we need in before `em`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It isn't working as expected yet, but I think, we are getting there! For some reason I get the warning `awk: warning: regexp escape sequence '\_' is not a known regexp operator`. Then, in the output, parts of the text are missing. Possibly, the command assumes that the pattern only can appear at the end of a line? In particular, the last line of my sample text is missing in the output.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, I have another followup question though: I noticed that the lines are too long, so I'd like to scale them down. I tried to define a width variable with `width = gsub(/\\_/, "", $i)` after the `if` line and then plug in `$width` in front of `em` (in order to scale width), but this completely breaks the command. Could you point me to my mistake or is it better to open a new question on this?

Comment: You need to use `width` instead of `$width` as `$` is to be used for positional fields only.

Comment: It's better, but still doesn't work. It appends a `\rule[-0.1ex]{em}{0.5pt}` to every line...

Comment: I edited the question with what I tried to do.

Comment: You have accepted this answer, which indicates that you are satisfied with it. Instead of heaping on new requirements, probably better to post a new question with the new problem. (By all means do link back to this question for context.)