# Bash: define a temporary variable inside an awk call, process and use it inside awk

Tags: variables, awk

I got a very helpful reply proposing the following `awk` call at [Bash: Search for consecutive repetitions of a pattern and replace it with a string containing the number of repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001977/bash-search-for-consecutive-repetitions-of-a-pattern-and-replace-it-with-a-stri)

```
awk '{
for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
   if ($i ~ /\\_/)
      $i = "\\rule[-0.1ex]{" gsub(/\\_/, "", $i) "em}{0.5pt}" $i
} 1' file
```

Now I need to redefine the return value of the `gsub` call before plugging it into the definition of `$i`. To be more precise, I need to multiply it by a number between 0 and 1 to scale it down a bit. Let's assume, the number is 0.5 for concreteness. I tried the following:

```
awk '{
for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
   if ($i ~ /\\_/)
      width = $((gsub(/\\_/, "", $i) * 0.5))
      $i = "\\rule[-0.1ex]{" width "em}{0.5pt}" $i
} 1' file
```

But this doesn't work, it just appends `\\rule[-0.1ex]{em}{0.5pt}` to every line of the file. How can I make it work?

Comment: To be honest, it even failed with `width = gsub(/\\_/, "", $i)`, so without any scaling, so there must by some other syntax problem here as well.

Comment: `awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /\\_/) $i = "\\rule[-0.1ex]{" gsub(/\\_/, "", $i)*.5 "em}{0.5pt}" $i} 1' file` should work for you

Comment: Thanks again, this worked like a charm! Awk seems to be quite smart here!

Comment: Please don't make us go clicking around other questions to piece together your requirements - [edit] **this** question so it contains it's own [mcve] and makes sense stand-alone.

Comment: You don't need to follow the link to piece together anything. The question is self-contained and the link is there for the case that anybody is interested in why I need to multiply the `gsub` output inside the `awk` call. The question also received two replies both of which were on point, so I think that it was perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You don't need to store output of `gsub` in a variable as you can perform arithmetic inline itself like this:

```bash
awk '{
for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
   if ($i ~ /\\_/)
      $i = "\\rule[-0.1ex]{" gsub(/\\_/, "", $i) * .5 "em}{0.5pt}" $i
} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put the multiplication inside `$()`, it means to use the product as a field number and return the contents of that field. If you just want to set `width` to the product, don't use `$()`.

You also need braces to group multiple statements in the body of `if`.

```
   if ($i ~ /\\_/) {
      width = gsub(/\\_/, "", $i) * 0.5;
      $i = "\\rule[-0.1ex]{" width "em}{0.5pt}" $i
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! I think, there is some superfluous closing bracket after the multiplication with a missing opening bracket, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Without sample input/output this is obviously an untested guess but it looks like you're trying to do this:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { ptSz = 0.5 }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
           if ( reps = gsub(/\\_/, "", $i) ) {
              $i = "\\rule[-0.1ex]{" (reps * ptSz) "em}{" ptSz "pt}" $i
           }
        }
        print
    }
' file
```

Regarding `width = $((gsub(/\\_/, "", $i) * 0.5))` - that `$(( ... ))` is `bash` syntax. `awk` is not `bash`, it's a completely different tool with it's own language with it's own syntax and semantics, far more similar to `C` than to `bash`.